# Django REST Framework - pass related field in POST data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `Django 2.0` and `Django REST Framework`

I have a model to store contact's address like

```
class ContactAddress(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    postal = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
```

I have two more models to store `state` and `country`

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='Country Name')


class State(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='State Name')
```

I want to pass `state` field with `POST` data while creating a new `address` record

**app/serializers.py**

```
class ContactAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactAddress
        depth = 2
        fields = (
            'id', 'city', 'postal', 'state'
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
```

and my `POST` data

```
[
    {
        "city": "City Name",
        "postal": "110011",
        "state": "Bihar"
    }
]
```

But there is no `state` data in `validated data`. Printing `validate_data` return

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    print(validated_data)

{'city': 'City Name', 'postal': '110011', 'contact': <Contact: contact_object>}
```

**How can I pass POST data for related field?**

Comment: include the pk for state in your post

Answer (score 0):

state property has foreign key to another model. If you want to use state property in serializer class, cannot behave like simple property

First, write a serializer for state model, then use this serializer class in contact address class

```
class StateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class meta:
         Fields = ('name')

class ContactAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

state = StateSerializer()
class Meta:
    model = ContactAddress
    depth = 2
    fields = (
        'id', 'city', 'postal', 'state'
    )

def create(self, validated_data):
    print(validated_data)
```

Comment: I want to be able to pass `contact_pk` in the request by name `state`. So, I only want to read extra data that I'm passing in the `POST` data. Why `state` data or any field that in not in the `fields` are not showing?